# Trying to replace last character in string, instead string duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ofusec/2/

When you open the DIV (Customize or Personalize) the function acts as it should, truncate the "+" and replace with a "-" symbol, however when a user closes the DIV the string is duplicated and placed in.

I would like the closing to act the same as the opening (truncate and replace last character)

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="customize" class="leftDiv">
    <span class="smallTitle"  onclick="toggle_expand('customizePort');">Customize Portfolio &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; +</span><br />
    <div class="leftDivContent" id="customizePort">
    LAYOUT:<BR />
    NAVIGATION:<BR />
    BACKGROUND COLOR:<BR />
    FONT COLOR:<BR />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="personalize" class="leftDiv">
    <span class="smallTitle" onclick="toggle_expand('personalizePort');">Personalize Portfolio &nbsp;&nbsp; +</span><br />
    <div class="leftDivContent" id="personalizePort">
        HEADER IMAGE:<BR />
        ARTIST STATEMENT:<br />
        CONTACT INFORMATION:<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function toggle_expand(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = $(e).siblings().text();
    if( $(e).css('display') === 'none' ){
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var newText = text.replace("+","-");
            $(e).siblings().text( newText );
        });
    } else {
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var newText = text.replace("-","+");
            $(e).siblings().text( newText );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this appears to have the effect you describe:

```
function toggle_expand(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = $(e).siblings("span").text();
    if( $(e).css('display') === 'none' ){
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var newText = $(e).siblings().text( text.slice(0, -1)+"-" );
        });
    } else {
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            text = $(e).siblings("span").text( text.slice(0, -1)+"+" );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason this happen is that there is an empty text node that is also a sibling, so you end up setting the string to 2 elements, then 4, ...

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you!So I can better understand whats going on, what element contains the empty text node?

Comment: #customizePort has 2 siblings, a span and a br (as @Explosion Pills pointed out below, not a text node)

Answer (score 0):

Your `siblings` selector lacks specificity.  Humorously, the `<br>` is incorrectly having the same text added to it, but it is initially obscured when the dropdown div is displayed.

```
function toggle_expand(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var $title = $(e).siblings(".smallTitle");
    var text = $title.text();
```

Refer to `$title` instead of `$(e).siblings("span")` in the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

what about little `regex` love:

```
function toggle_expand(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = $(e).siblings("span").text();
    if( $(e).css('display') === 'none' ){
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            var newText = $(e).siblings().text( text.replace(/\+/,'-'));
        });
    } else {
        $(e).slideToggle('fast', function(){
            text = $(e).siblings("span").text( text.replace(/-/,'+'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was reading up on regex while posting this, and messed around a bit. I don't fully understand the syntax involved! If you could explain why all the forward / backward slashes are needed I would probably use it, because it reads better.

Comment: well the first and last **/** are to define `regex` the one **\** is to escape `+` (the one before `-` was superfluous and I have removed it). You can read more about JS regex here:http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html